# pep8 only registers the first value in the "ignore" parameter

Tags: python, pep8

I am running pep8 on the following code, in a file called `main.py`:

```
class Task(ndb.Model):

    index = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
```

When `~/.config/pep8` looks like this:

```
[pep8]
ignore = W291, E251
```

running `$ pep8 main.py` gives the following output:

```
main.py:49:41: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
main.py:49:43: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
main.py:51:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
```

However when I swap the order of the error codes to `ignore = E251, W291` and run the same command on the same file, I get:

```
main.py:50:50: W291 trailing whitespace
main.py:51:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
```

In other words, only the first pep8 code is being ignored. It's maddening. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

I'm having the same problem with Python linting in Sublime Text 3, which is defined by the ignore parameter in the user-defined `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`; not sure if that could be related (I'm following the instructions in https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/).

Thanks!

Comment: You want `ignore = W291,E251` (no space)

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out while I was writing up the post actually, but decided to post and "self-answer" in case anyone else ran into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the spaces between my PEP8 error codes. The example configuration [in the documentation](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration) reads:

```
[pep8]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
```